# Ansible vars_prompt for roles

Tags: ansible

I have a set of `Ansible` playbooks and the main yml file is like this

```
- hosts: all 
  roles:
    - common
    - install_nginx
```

I want to add the confirm message when I trigger the playbook. I tried this and did not work

```
- hosts: all
  vars_prompt:
    - name: CONFIRM
      prompt: Just to confirm you will install stuff
  tasks:
    - fail: no deployment this time
      when: CONFIRM != 'yes'
  roles:
    - common
    - install_nginx
```

How can I use `vars_prompt` in this case without modify every `role`?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What happens? Does the `fail` task trigger but then the playbook still continue? Or does it not run at all?

Comment: Yes. The `fail` was triggered but it still continue to run the `roles` tasks. Something like the `fail` only affect for the tasks that belongs to `tasks` block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the output from running your playbook with the `vars_prompt` you'll see that the `fail` task runs after the other roles. This is also mentioned in the [Ansible docs for playbooks and roles](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#roles):

> If the play still has a ‘tasks’ section, those tasks are executed
>   after roles are applied.

As the above docs also mention if you want to force a task to run before any roles then you can use `pre_tasks`.

So to have your confirmation style prompt you could simply do this:

```
- hosts: all
  vars_prompt:
    - name: CONFIRM
      prompt: Just to confirm you will install stuff
  pre_tasks:
    - fail: no deployment this time
      when: CONFIRM != 'yes'
  roles:
    - common
    - install_nginx
```

Comment: Awesome. Work perfectly!

Comment: I use this approach, but I find it cumbersome. I have a `setup.yml` in which I comment out the roles I don't need, but that means I should also comment out the prompts.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure, but the way this works is :

```
- hosts: all

  vars_prompt:
    - name: "confirm"
      prompt: Just to confirm you will install stuff 
      private: no
      default: "no"
  tasks:
    - name: Install Nginx
      apt: name=nginx
      sudo: true 
      when:  confirm == "yes"
```

Now if we need to call each role based on a condition , i suppose we shoud be using `tags`.

Comment: Ya your code will work since it will call the `tasks` but in my case it will load the `roles` and if I add the same task to verify before the `roles` block. It will not work.

Answer (score 1):

**How to use Ansible vars_prompt for roles**

i got the solution to use vars_prompts in ansible role section

i have directly included vars_prompt in my main.yml playbook as like before

```
- hosts: "{{HOSTS}}"
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  roles:
    - syslog
    - splunk
    - nmon
    - trendmicro
    - user-creation
    - extened-history
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "user_password"
      prompt: "Enter User Password"
      private: yes
      confirm: yes
==========================================================
```

Below is the ansible command to execute the playbook

```
# ansible-playbook ort-linux.yml -e "HOSTS=TESTSERVER"
Enter User Password:
confirm Enter User Password:

========================================================
```

Below is my roles playbook for user id creation

```
---
  - name: "Task-1 create Linux Team user"
    user:
     name: "{{item}}"
     comment: LINUX_UNIX_TEAM
     group: LINUX_UNIX_TEAM
     shell: /bin/bash
     generate_ssh_key: yes
     ssh_key_bits: 2048
     ssh_key_file: .ssh/id_rsa
     createhome: yes
     password: "{{user_password|password_hash('sha512')}}"

    loop:
     - sam
     - jack
     - kumar
     - ravi
    tags: linuxuser
```

Comment: Is this solution still working for you? I cannot get it to work in Ansible 2.9. In my "parent" role I have defined vars_prompt in the main.yml file there. In my "child" role I am including the parent role via the "roles:" statement. When I execute the main playbook for my child role, I do not see the prompts defined in the parents main.yml file.